# Redirect to without slash

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to redirect url with get parameters to without ending slash.

`/?a=b&PAGEN_1=2&c=d/` -> `/?a=b&PAGEN_1=2&c=d`

How can i do that?

no work:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.+)PAGEN_1=2(.+)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1? [L,QSA,R=301]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule instead:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}?%1 [L,R=301,NE]
```

Comment: You save my day :) Thank you!